# Value From DropDownList not being set

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a dropdownlist being populated from a database. This is working fine. It's binding and showing the correct data as expected. But when I change it's value and try to save it to the database, nothing is being saved and this causes a NULL exception.

Here's my C# code:

```
protected DropDownList ddStatus;
protected RadioButtonList rblInternalNotes;

public void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        ValidateSession();

        ddStatus_Bind();

        rblInternalNotes.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("External","0"));
        rblInternalNotes.Items.Insert(1,new ListItem("Internal","1"));

        btnSave.Attributes.Add("onClick","return checkForm();");

                       /* code continues */
}
```

To test my Save button, I'm using this:

```
public void btnSave_OnClick(object Sender, System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs E)
    {
        Response.Write(ddStatus.SelectedValue);
        Response.End();
```

The code for the binding is:

```
protected void ddStatus_Bind()
{
    SqlConnection Conn = GetConnection();
    string SQL;
    SqlCommand Cmd;
    SqlDataAdapter DAdpt = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet DSet = new DataSet();

    SQL = "SELECT Name,StatusID FROM tbl_test";
    Cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL,Conn);

    DAdpt.SelectCommand = Cmd;
    DAdpt.Fill(DSet);

    ddStatus.DataSource = DSet;
    ddStatus.DataBind();

    Conn.Close();
}
```

And this is my front end code:

```
<TR ID="trStatus" RunAt="Server" visible="false">
    <TD Class="Spreadsheet"><B>Status</B></TD>
    <TD Class="Spreadsheet">
        <ASP:DropDownList ID="ddStatus" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="StatusID" AppendDataBoundItems="True" RunAt="Server"></ASP:DropDownList>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

The Save button:

```
<ASP:ImageButton ID="btnSave" OnClick="btnSave_OnClick" ImageURL="/images/buttons/btnSave.gif" Border="0" RunAt="Server"/>
```

and I have

```
 <FORM EnableViewState = false runat="server">
```

as the form tag and

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" debug="True" Inherits="Default" src="Default.cs" validateRequest="false" EnableEventValidation="false"%>
```

as the page tag.

If I remove `EnableViewState = false` in the form tag, it will work but only after a second click. It will never save on the first click.

Can anyone please help on that? Thanks as always.

Comment: keep `ddStatus_Bind();` out of `IsPostBack` condition check

Comment: Did it and now the value is always the first one.

Comment: good, there is nothing wrong in your code; now keep it back inside `IsPostBack` and add `EnableViewState="true"` on the Page tag.

Comment: Now nothing is being returned again

Comment: if you are going to check `If(!IsPostBack){ }` then I would expect to see an else.. this is a typical PostBack issue / mistake that people make use the debugger and you will quickly notice where to place the binding / fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work!

I just did the binding at the initialization of the page like this

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{

        ddStatus_Bind();

        rblInternalNotes.Items.Insert(0,new ListItem("External","0"));
        rblInternalNotes.Items.Insert(1,new ListItem("Internal","1"));

}
```

I hope that helps other people who are facing the same problem.

P.S: I don't understand the downvote on this post though.